# Deserialize a JSON Dictionary into a custom class

Tags: objective-c, json, json-deserialization

I'm developing an iOS 5.0 and above application using latest SDK.

I get a `NSDictionary` using this code:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

This dictionary has class properties as keys, and each property value as values.

I'm trying to develop a generic method:

```
+ (id)FromJSON:(NSDictionary*)jsonDic toClass:(NSString*)className;
```

This method will instance a var using `className` parameter (by the way, can I create a instance object using a `NSString` with its class name?).

But my problem is have can I know the type for each `jsonDic` value. I can get each property name and try to guest its type (`NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc.).

**Any advice about how to do it?**

Comment: Have your used RestKit ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem this way:

```
+ (id)FromJSON:(NSDictionary*)jsonDic toClass:(NSString*)className
{
    Class ObjectClass = NSClassFromString(className);

    if (ObjectClass == nil)
        return nil;

    NSObject* loadedObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];

    [loadedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:jsonDic];

    return loadedObject;
}
```

Any comment?